# Programmatically Add Fake Hardware in Windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++, drivers

I have created a fake usb flash driver driver in Windows that will fake Windows into thinking that a new hardware device is attached. I have also found the APIs that allow me to enumerate the hardware attached (so I know which device is my fake driver).

The problem is I only want to attach the hardware when my program is running, and I don't want it to be accessible when my program is not running.

How can I programmatically add this hardware or enable/disable this driver? Someone suggested the right nomenclature is "load/unload".

Using VC++ with Windows APIs on Windows 7 and higher.

Comment: By unloading your driver when your application exits?

Comment: Yeah, I think that would work, but how would I do that?

Comment: In the simplest case the same way like you load the driver right now.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [C++ class wrapper to load/unload device drivers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31905/A-C-class-wrapper-to-load-unload-device-drivers) from code project.